# React - Push array to State

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

```
getInitialState: function() {
     p:{'Keeper' : [] , 'Defenders': [] , 'Midfield' : [], 'Forwards' : []}}
}
onUpdatePlayers : function (newState) {
    var pos;

    if (newState.position.includes('Back')) {
        pos = 'Defenders'
    } else if (newState.position.includes('Midfield')){
        pos = 'Midfield'
    } else if (newState.position.includes('Forward')) {
        pos = 'Forwards'
    } else {
        pos = newState.position;
    }

    this.state.p[pos].push(newState)
}
```

Basically , I want to push some arrays into multiple state's property.
Somehow, I need to change this code "this.state.p[pos].push(newState)" to using **this.setState**. I've google it and found something like

```
    this.setState({
        p : this.state.p[pos].concat([newState])
    });
```

Obviously, It does not help at all. Can you please advise me on this ? 
It will be Big Thanks,

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do really need your state to be deeply nested you'll need to replace entire `p` property with new object. For example using `Object.assign`

```
this.setState({
  p: Object.assign(this.state.p, {
    [pos]: this.state.p[pos].concat(newState)
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Yury, It does work with your method. !!
but , I feel maybe It's not the best way to define the multiple state's array using getInitialState method. 

Let's say I don't have any InitialState. 


Is more clean and better way to return same result?  but not using deeply nested or using Object.assign ?

Comment: "It does work with your method." could you be more precise on this? If newState is array this code should concat it with the one you have in state. `Object.assign` works 1 level deep. You need to write some code or use a library (for example lodash) to make deep cloning.

Answer (score 0):

[Danny Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6429008/danny-kim), you are missing quotes on the new key you wanted to add. Change your last line to

```
this.state.p['pos'].push(newState)
```

Comment: pos  is variables scope. Not a string. 
Thanks anyway